# Ruby on rails 4, Active admin customize devise signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I am using ruby on rails 4 and installed Activeadmin gem, it automatically installed devise gem and now i am able to sign up for normal users beside having the activeadmin panel and users, The problem is that i want to edit the sign up page here "/users/sign_up "  and i couldn't find the devise views or activeadmin view, I searched the project folder also and only found "devise.rb" and no views for it.

Comment: yea of course , i accepted it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rails generate devise:views` command to generate views. Views will appear under `/views/devise`.